# CsvHelper - GetRecords is not returning anything

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

GetRecords is not returning anything. Can you please help me figure out what I'm missing?

```
var csvContent = parseApiResponse["staffTeamCsv"].ToString();
        TextReader sr = new StringReader(csvContent);

        var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = "|"
        };

    var csv = new CsvReader(sr, csvConfiguration);

    var records = csv.GetRecords<StaffTeam>().ToList();
        
        var converted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records);
        var convertedContent = JArray.Parse(converted);`
```

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X2Sb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the attached screenshot (please post contents in it here as text as well), your 'csvContent' variable contents look like this:

```
"Id|Name|1|nam|2|name"
```

That's not a properly formatted representation of a CSV file.

Assuming your column headers are `Id` and `Name`, and the rest is the data, they should be separated by a return. So your string should look like this:

```
var csvContent = "Id|Name\n1|nam\n2|name";
```

Your `StaffTeam` class should also look like this:

```
public class StaffTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Could also be string
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially, your code is fine, your data isn't.

Comment: If that is literally what @amsa is receiving and it can't be changed, they may have to manually read in the data, similar to what's shown here: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand

Comment: You're right! My data was incorrect. Thank you!!

Comment: @amsa if the answer helped please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem where I always had zero records although my StreamReader was correctly reading the .csv file. Turns out I copied only half of the .csv document for testing which meant that I had no csv header which lead to CsvHelper returning 0 records without error.